# Library for converting JSON string to JS code snippet

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say we have a JSON string :

```
let json = `{
    "book": {
        "name": "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire",
        "author": "J. K. Rowling",
        "year": 2000,
        "characters": ["Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger", "Ron Weasley"],
        "genre": "Fantasy Fiction",
        "price": {
            "paperback": "$10.40", "hardcover": "$20.32", "kindle": "$4.11"
        }
    }
}`;
```

I can parse it using `JSON.parse(json)`

But what if I want to create its js code snippet from string like this :

```
  let json = {
    book: {
      name: "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire",
      author: "J. K. Rowling",
      year: 2000,
      characters: ["Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger", "Ron Weasley"],
      genre: "Fantasy Fiction",
      price: {
        paperback: "$10.40",
        hardcover: "$20.32",
        kindle: "$4.11"
      }
    }
  };
```

Is there any library available for it?

Crossposted from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304833/8249665) to ask for a library rather than a custom implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON5:

```
let json = JSON5.stringify(JSON.parse(`{
    "book": {
        "name": "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire",
        "author": "J. K. Rowling",
        "year": 2000,
        "characters": ["Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger", "Ron Weasley"],
        "genre": "Fantasy Fiction",
        "price": {
            "paperback": "$10.40", "hardcover": "$20.32", "kindle": "$4.11"
        }
    }
}`), { space: 2 });

console.log('let json = ' + json + ';');
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/json5@2.2.0/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```